# Alt + Number key combination in notebooks

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, character-encoding, special-characters, alt-code

If you do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> in a PC you will get "@" and so on for most characters.

I could not find out way yet to use this very helpful resource in notebooks.

Can this be done?

<sup>I would like if possible an operating system / computer brand agnostic answer because it will be more helpful to others (and me) but if this is not possible, here are my specifications:


 - OS: Ubuntu 10.10

 - Brand: DELL Vostro 3500

 - Keyboard Configuration: Spanish - Spain</sup>

Comment: Could you post a picture of your keyboard?

Comment: @AndrejaKo: The best pic I found so far http://i.imgur.com/8NzVB.jpg

Comment: Well the numeric keyboard is there.... Could you activate it under windows? Maybe ubuntu doesn't have needed kernel modules compiled. Also try with Fn and one of the F keys. Maybe it'll do something.

Answer (score 2):

Some notebooks (actually all I've seen which don't have separate keypad and aren't apple) have a numlock button and a numeric keypad printed over right side of the character area of the keyboard.

So check your manual and see if there's a way to enable the numpad. It could happen that there isn't a way to do that.

A negative side of that is that you can't use the numpad as letters until you turn the numlock off.

Comment: I tried with `Fn` and it's not working I'm trying to figure out a way to do block the numpad...

Answer (score 2):

On most laptop/netbook keyboards, holding down the *Fn* key activates the numeric keypad built into the keyboard. The keys involved vary depending on manufacturer, but they're generally on the right side of the keyboard and have numbers/punctuation on them in a faint color (orange on my Gateway) in the top right corner of the keycap.  I can hold down Fn

Comment: Yes, thanks but it's not really working... (in this case at least)

Comment: @Trufa: Then use NumLock instead.

Comment: @paradroid: Couldn't figure out how to do this yet (just in case I know how to do this generally, just not in this OS with this notebook)

Comment: I've never had this work in X, only in Windows. Sorry, I posted before you updated the question to say you use Ubuntu (I think). There are lots of X-specific keyboard shortcut programs that you could use, but you're seemingly looking for an OS-independent solution, and I do not believe there is one.

Answer (score 1):

You need a numeric keypad to use these combinations; they will not work with the number keys in the row above the letter keys.  If you want to use these combinations, consider purchasing a USB numpad.

Comment: That exactly was my point, no workaround? :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + left <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
2. Type <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>.
3. Release <kbd>Fn</kbd> + left <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

---

*I did not notice this is old question, maybe this answer will still help someone.*